# Watch height of an element in VueJS

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there any way to set a watcher on the height of an element in VueJS?

I am trying to fix the filters part on a search result page. but if the results change there is no way to find about it and unfix the filters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the height with $ref.yourElement.clientHeight, after the search result returns the data. With that, you can set the height as part of your data{} section, and from there apply a watcher. Check [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/7ptLwo0k/)

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    height: 0
  },
  methods: {
    calculateHeight() {
      this.height = this.$refs.app.clientHeight;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Also, you can get the element by just calling this.$el.clientHeight

Comment: What about images that are loaded out of the response data? They will change the height of the element. After that you have to rerun this function again. But when do you know the loading of the image has been completed?

Comment: won't work with something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kja5rsuv/

Answer (score 28):

You could use the [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)  and integrate it into your Vue-Component

```js
function observeHeight() {
  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(function() {
     console.log("Size changed");
  });

 resizeObserver.observe(document.getElementById('yourId'));
}

function changeHeight() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('yourId');
  
  console.log('...loading data...')
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    elem.style = "height: 200px";
  }, 3000);
  
}

observeHeight();
changeHeight();
```

```css
#yourId {
  background-color: beige;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="yourId">
  
</div>
```

Comment: This is the better answer for complex use cases. I had a situation where I had an element that was growing based on other Vue data, and I was always 1 render cycle behind with the true width to adjust some dynamic padding -- this is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are want to observe an element inside a component then use an arrow function:

```
observeHeight() {
      const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {

        console.log('Size changed:', document.getElementById('elementId').clientHeight;);
      });

      resizeObserver.observe(document.getElementById('elementId'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script setup>

const list = ref([
    'sdg sdfg sdfhs fhseraj sdhbfjasvfkjvaskjvfuas', 
    'ggs dfg s', 
    'sdg s sfg sfgs dfg'
])

const itemRefs = ref([])

onMounted(() => {
   alert(itemRefs.value[1].clientHeight)
})

</script>


<template>
  <ul style="width: 50px">
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="itemRefs">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```